# How to create href link inside array

Tags: php, mysql, matomo

Actualy I have to populate table data using php array to my dashboard. The table contains the URL. I need to set href which is used to redirect to the dynamic link.(below is my while loop code). I have tried creating href using below the single line echo php code.It worked and I got the clickable link, but it didn't return data inside the table. It showed the data in the table without any alignment.

```
echo '<html><head></head><a href="'.$data['link'].'" target="_blank">'.$data['link'].'</a></html>';
```

But I want to create href inside array
kindly anyone help us.

```
public function getTemperatures()
{
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user     = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $mysql_database = "new";
    $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");// we are now connected to database

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM website"); // selecting data through mysql_query()
    $pie = mysql_query("select count(*) from website where status = 'Error'");

    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        //echo '<html><head></head><a href="'.$data['link'].'" target="_blank">'.$data['link'].'</a></html>';
        $temperatures[] = array(
            'label1' => $data['link'],
            'label2' => $data['time'],
            'label3' => $data['os'],
            'label4' => $data['browser'],
            'label5' => $data['status'],
            'label6' => $data['location'],
            array('label6' => $data['widget_load_time'])
        );
    }    
    return DataTable::makeFromIndexedArray($temperatures);
}
```

Comment: You really need to [stop using mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Where's your `<body>`-Tag? Are you trying to echo several `html` elements? That won't work. Wrap your `html` (and body) around the whole thing.

Comment: [`mysql_*` extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: Your question and your code do not seem to have anything to do with each other. VTC as unclear!

Comment: Baskar..I'm unclear on exactly what your wanting your results to look like. Can you show us what your expecting to see ?

Comment: @Machavity i really loved your comment :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pls add this line

```
'label1' => '<a href="'.$data['link'].'" target="_blank">'.$data['link'].'</a>',
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the solution already. Just change how you assign 'label1' to the below.

```
public function getTemperatures()
{
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user     = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $mysql_database = "new";
    $bd =  mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");// we are now connected to database

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM website"); // selecting data through mysql_query()
     $pie = mysql_query("select count(*) from website where status = 'Error'");

    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $temperatures[] = array(
            'label1' => '<a href="'.$data['link'].'" target="_blank">'.$data['link'].'</a>',
            'label2' => $data['time'],
            'label3' => $data['os'],
            'label4' => $data['browser'],
            'label5' => $data['status'],
            'label6' => $data['location'],
            array('label6' => $data['widget_load_time'])
        );
    }    
    return DataTable::makeFromIndexedArray($temperatures);
}
```

And as the comments mentioned, avoid using mysql_* functions as they're no longer supported (which should be reason enough)

Comment: Why are you "kinda' guessing"?  A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @jay guessing cause I'm not sure what he's asking for. I'll  edit my answer to atleast explain what it does. Thanks.